# useAnimatedGestureHandler not woking in react-native-reanimated library in react-native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, animation, hook

I'm newbie for ReactNative and I'm doing SwipeButton for my project. But i have issue for useAnimatedGestureHandler as below:

```
TypeError: (0, _reactNativeReanimated.useAnimatedGestureHandler) is not a function. (In '(0, _reactNativeReanimated.useAnimatedGestureHandler)(0)', '(0, _reactNativeReanimated.useAnimatedGestureHandler)' is undefined)
```

I think it may be because its version is Reanimated-v2 while I am using Reanimated-v1, can anyone here convert this code to Reanimated-v1 for me,

My code look like as below:

```
import { View, Text, ViewBase } from 'react-native';
import { PanGestureHandler } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Animated, {
    interpolate,
    useAnimatedGestureHandler,
    useSharedValue,
    useAnimatedStyle
} from 'react-native-reanimated';

const SampleTest = (props) => {
    const buttonVal = useSharedValue(0);

    const handleGesture = useAnimatedGestureHandler({
        onStart: (_, ctx) => {
            ctx.x = buttonVal.value;
        },
        onActive: ({ translationX }, ctx) => {
            buttonVal.value = translationX + ctx.x;
        },
        onEnd: ({ translationX }) => {
            if (translationX > _WIDTH / 3) {
                buttonVal.value = withTiming(_WIDTH * 0.85);
            } else {
                buttonVal.value = withTiming(0);
            }
        }
    });
    const pathAnimatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
        return {
            width: interpolate(
                buttonVal.value,
                [0, _WIDTH * 0.85],
                [50, _WIDTH * 0.85]
            ),
            height: 50,
            borderRadius: 25,
            backgroundColor: 'gray',
            position: 'absolute'
        };
    });
    return (
        <>
            <PanGestureHandler onGestureEvent={handleGesture}>
                <Animated.View
                    style={{
                        width: '85%',
                        height: 50,
                        borderRadius: 25,
                        backgroundColor: 'yellow',
                        shadowColor: 'gray',
                        justifyContent: 'center',
                        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
                        shadowOpacity: 0.25,
                        shadowRadius: 3.84,
                        elevation: 5
                    }}
                >
                    <Text
                        style={{
                            textAlign: 'center',
                            opacity: 0.9,
                            color: 'white',

                            fontWeight: 'bold'
                        }}
                    >
                        Swipe button
                    </Text>
                    <Animated.View style={pathAnimatedStyle}></Animated.View>
                </Animated.View>
            </PanGestureHandler>
        </>
    );
};
```

Thanks, everyone.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `<PanGestureHandler/>` handler with `<GestureHandlerRootView/>`